# How to have dynamic version name at run time when deploying google app engine in Travis CI?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I am studying to automate the build and deployment of my google app engine application in Travis, so far it allows me to have static or predefined version name during deployment in **.travis.yml**.

Is there any way to make it dynamically generated at runtime? Like for example below in my .travis.yml file, I have deployment for production and staging version of the application, both are named or labeled as **production** and **qa-staging**, and I would like to suffix the version names with a timestamp or anything as long as it would be unique every successful build and deployment.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- "10"

before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_c423808ed406_key -iv $encrypted_c423808ed406_iv
  -in gae-creds.json.enc -out gae-creds.json -d
- chmod +x test.sh
- cat gae-creds.json

install:
- npm install

script:
- "./test.sh"

deploy:
  - provider: gae
    skip_cleanup: true
    keyfile: gae-creds.json
    project: traviscicd
    no_promote: true
    version: qa-staging
    on:
      branch: staging
  - provider: gae
    skip_cleanup: true
    keyfile: gae-creds.json
    project: traviscicd
    version: production
    on:
      branch: master
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with https://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html ?

Im not sure if the context is the correct but seems a good and elegant option for your yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [`go generate`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Generate_Go_files_by_processing_source) to generate a version string that can be included? You need to run `go generate` as part of the build process for it to work, though.